# R - Assigning ranked value in 1 data frame, conditionally based on deprecating value in a separate data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I have two related data frames:

```
     ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Group6 Group7 Group8 Group9 Group10 Assign1
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1     1      9      6      5     10      7      1      4      8      2       3 ""     
2     2      8      6      5      9      3      1      2      7      4      10 ""     
3     3      6      3     10      9      1      2      5      8      7       4 ""     
4     4      5      9      3      1      8      4      7      6     10       2 ""     
5     5     10      7      8      2      3      6      4      5      1       9 ""     
6     6      9      3      1      4      8      6      2      5      7      10 "" 

df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Group1 = c(9, 2, 6, 
5, 10, 9), Group2 = c(6, 6, 3, 9, 7, 3), Group3 = c(5, 5, 10, 
3, 8, 1), Group4 = c(10, 9, 9, 1, 2, 4), Group5 = c(7, 3, 1, 
8, 3, 8), Group6 = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 6), Group7 = c(4, 2, 5, 7, 
4, 2), Group8 = c(8, 7, 8, 6, 5, 5), Group9 = c(2, 4, 7, 10, 
1, 7), Group10 = c(3, 10, 4, 2, 9, 10), Assign1 = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

and

```
Group    Size
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 Group1      5
 2 Group2      2
 3 Group3      4
 4 Group4     55
 5 Group5     10
 6 Group6      1
 7 Group7     25
 8 Group8     12
 9 Group9      5
10 Group10     6

df2 <- structure(list(Group = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", 
"Group5", "Group6", "Group7", "Group8", "Group9", "Group10"), 
    Size = c(5, 2, 4, 55, 10, 1, 25, 12, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to populate `Assign1` in df1 as the column name of the lowest value for each `ID` (for example, row 1 would have a value of Group6). Each row contains unique values between 1:10.

The more complex aspect of this is with each assignment in df1, I need to deprecate the value of `Size` in df2 for the matched `Group`. So, having assigned Group6 to row 1 in df1, the value of `Size` for Group6 in df2 would decrease from 1 to 0. Once the value of `Size` in df2 reaches 0, it can no longer be assigned in df1 and instead I need to assign the *next* lowest ranked group (i.e. the column in df1 that contains a 2, assuming that the selected Group has `Size` > 0 in df2).

I'm fairly new to looping in R. Fully aware that the below is not the correct syntax, but shows where my attempt at logic is going:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
select(minvalue in 2:11) & 
df1$Assign1 <- match(colname(df1) to df2$Group) where df2$Size > 0 & 
df2$Size <- df2$Size - 1
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
  ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Group6 Group7 Group8 Group9 Group10 Assign1
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1     1      9      6      5     10      7      1      4      8      2       3 Group6 
2     2      2      6      5      9      3      1      2      7      4      10 Group7 
3     3      6      3     10      9      1      2      5      8      7       4 Group5 
4     4      5      9      3      1      8      4      7      6     10       2 Group4 
5     5     10      7      8      2      3      6      4      5      1       9 Group9 
6     6      9      3      1      4      8      6      2      5      7      10 Group3
```

Grateful for any help in pointing me towards the end goal.

Comment: updated the edit - had inadvertently updated the ID value rather than one of the ranked columns. There will be no duplicates within a single row. Thanks again!

Comment: Please check the updated solution

Comment: Your expected output for row 3 in Assign1 is. `Group5` and its value is 9 for that row.  Not clear

Comment: Iin the input your Group5 value for row 3 is 1.  and as it is already being used for 1st row, how can the third row for Assign1 be Group5.  From my understanding, it would be Group2

Comment: updated, apologies my attempt to edit within stackoverflow didn't work as planned. Row 3 would be Group 5 now, as it is the 1 rank and Group 5 still would have space available.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question

Comment: The context is that I'd like to look across each row to find the lowest value, but if that lowest value has already been deprecated to 0 by the rows preceding it I need to go to the next available lowest value. So Group6 for row1, Group7 for row2 since Group6 now has a value of 0 in df2, Group5 for row3 since that is row3's lowest value and there is still space (starts with a value of 10).

Comment: If the first row is already selected with value 1, then how are you taking the Group5 for 3rd row, which also shows value 1.

Comment: Multiple IDs can contain the same value 1, as long as the size as defined in df2 allows for it. So in other words, 10 IDs could have a value of 1 for Group5, it would be the 11th that would be an issue (up to 5 for Group1, 2 for Group2, etc). Essentially the rows represent a survey response from an individual where they have been asked to rank their preference of joining a Group. We award them with their top rank, as long as the Group is not already full. If full, we move to their 2nd choice. If that is also full we move to their third choice. Row 1 has highest priority, and then we move down.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in the other direction i.e. once a value was selected, no longer it is used

Comment: How about the updated code in my post

Comment: hmm I don't see any additional code or your previous comment/answer

Comment: There was a bug in the code.  Can you check the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `for` loop

```
df1new <- data.table::copy(df1)
df2new <- data.table::copy(df2)

out <- character(0)
nm1 <- startsWith(names(df1), 'Group')
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1new))) {
   tmp_ind <- which.min(df1new[i, nm1])
   tmp_nm <- names(df1new)[nm1][tmp_ind]
   tmp_ind2 <- match(tmp_nm, df2new$Group)
   if(df2new$Size[tmp_ind2] < 1) {
      df1new[i, nm1][tmp_ind] <- NA
     tmp_ind <- which.min(df1new[i, nm1])
     tmp_nm <- names(df1new)[nm1][tmp_ind] 
     df2new$Size[tmp_ind2] <-  df2new$Size[tmp_ind2] - 1      
    } else {  
   
    df2new$Size[tmp_ind2] <-  df2new$Size[tmp_ind2] - 1  
   }
   
   out <- c(out, tmp_nm) 
   

}



df1$Assign1 <- out
df1$Assign1
#[1] "Group6" "Group7" "Group5" "Group4" "Group9" "Group3"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Group1 = c(9L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 9L), 
    Group2 = c(6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 3L), Group3 = c(5L, 5L, 10L, 
    3L, 8L, 1L), Group4 = c(10L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 4L), Group5 = c(7L, 
    3L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 8L), Group6 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L), 
    Group7 = c(4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 2L), Group8 = c(8L, 7L, 8L, 
    6L, 5L, 5L), Group9 = c(2L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 7L), Group10 = c(3L, 
    10L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 10L), Assign1 = c("", "", "", "", "", ""
    )), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun - this gets me so close! I chose a bad sample that didn't include any instances of this, but I need to prevent an assignment occurring if the value of `Size` hits 0 during the iteration. So for example, if row 1 has a value of 1 for `Group6` and so does row 2, I need row 2 to get the second choice (the column that has a 2) since Group6 is limited to 1 assignment per the `Size` column in df2. Any thoughts on how that would be possible?

Comment: @ardls Are you saying that the min value for each id should be unique

Comment: @ardls can you please update your example by `edit`ing your post and the exxpected output so that it becomes clear

Comment: Have just edited - in this case, row 1 gets a value of Group6. Moving to row2, we can't assign their min value since df2 only allows for 1 row to be assigned Group6 (the `Size` represents how many assignments for each Group are allowed). Thus for row2, we'd look at their next lowest value - in this case we'd assign them Group7. Essentially looking for the lowest value in df1 for a Group that hasn't been filled by assignments in the preceding rows (the full data set will have hundreds of rows, so in theory we may need to turn to option 3 or 4 if their options of 1 or 2 had reached 0 in df2).

Comment: @ardls For row 2, i.e. ID 8, there are two 1s.  What do you do with ties.  Are you going to remove those two because for row 1, 1 value is already used

Comment: sorry, inadvertently updated the ID instead of one of the values in the original edit. Have updated again - there will be no ties, each row will only have unique 1:10

Comment: @ardls I updated the post.  Please let me know if these are the values in the expected output

Comment: I think this will work! When I run it on the full data set of 600 rows, I do see some unexpected repeats (there are some Group6 values later in the data set, for example). This seems to cover the first reallocation but maybe struggles to remember that decremented value for the future rows? If that makes sense? But this at least gives me initial assignments that I can then compare against the size caps and see where there might be issues. Thanks again for sticking with all my edits and being such an immense help!

Comment: @ardls may be it needs a while loop.  I tested only for your example data.  So, there may be some logic that needs to be updatedd

Comment: I think you're right. I realized it only catches the first time a row matches with a `df2newSize` < 1 but doesn't cycle back through if the 2nd or 3rd minimum value also matches with a value < 1. I've adapted for my immediate needs to at least partially automate. Thanks again.

Comment: @ardls it needs a while or do while loop.

Comment: Managed to write my first while loop after some research and got my expected output. Would not have been able to do this without you @akrun - so appreciate it!

Comment: @ardls Glad that you were able to do this.  I think this you would not forget it and would be a great learning opportunity when you do by yourself